# How to disable inserting the same video in playlist using YouTube api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Currently I managed to add a video to existing playlist using Authorization and youtube v3 api in javascript.

I have a difficulty to know when the user is adding the same video several times, I only want to have only one instance of each video once. I searched in youtube api and find there is an error videoAlreadyInPlaylist but I didn't find how to enable this flag as part of the request the video to the playlist.
Currently I can add video as many times as the user wants.
How can I enable this option?

this is my code so far:

```
function addVideoToPlayList(pId, videosIdArray, index)
{
      var vId = videosIdArray[index];
      var details = {
            videoId: vId,
            kind: 'youtube#video'
      }

      var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
        part: 'snippet',
        resource: {
          snippet: {
            playlistId: pId,
            resourceId: details
          }
        }
      });
      request.execute(function(response) {
          console.log(response);

          if(videosIdArray.length == index+1)
          {
              //end! 
          }
          else{
              addVideoToPlayList(pId,videosIdArray,++index);
          }

        $('#status').html($('#status').html()+'<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre><br/>');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in the API, when adding the same video in a playlist there is no error returned [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=7020)

Until google will fix this issue, I ended up adding manually a button to remove all the duplicate values manually from the playlist.

Code:

```
function removeDuplicate()
{
    console.log(videoArr);
    var deleteVideoItems = [];
    $.each(videoArr, function(i, item1)
    {

        if (!(item1 === undefined || item1 === null))
        {
            var vId = item1.vId;
            $.each(videoArr, function(j, item2)
            {
                if(item1.vId === item2.vId && i!==j && deleteVideoItems.indexOf(item1)===-1)
                {
                    deleteVideoItems.push(item2);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(deleteVideoItems);

    deleteRecursianDuplicate(deleteVideoItems,0);

}

function deleteRecursianDuplicate(duplicateArr, index)
{
        var playlistVideoId = duplicateArr[index].vPlaylistId;

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.delete({
        part: 'snippet',
        id: playlistVideoId//,
    });
    request.execute(function(data) {

    var code = data.hasOwnProperty("code");
    if(data.hasOwnProperty('code')){
        var code = data.code;
        var message = data.data[0].message;
        alert("problem accures "+code+" "+message);
    }
    else{

        if(index+1 < duplicateArr.length)
        {
            deleteRecursianDuplicate(duplicateArr,++index);
        }
        else if(index+1 == duplicateArr.length)//we finished to delete all duplicate videos => refresh load list
        {
            $("button#load").click();
        }
    }

  });
}
```